# how to make the images in tpl fit in the panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have made an imageviewer using the dataviewer component but it seems that the images are just being displayed downward instead of fitting in the panel. Could someone help on how to make the images fit in the panel? Appreciate the help.

Here is my code:

```
var iPanel= new Ext.panel.Panel({
                                    width: 490,
                                    height: 500,
                                    layout: 'fit',
                                    title: 'Select an avatar',
                                    floating: true,
                                    closable : true,
                                    items: {
                                        extend: 'Ext.view.View',
                                        xtype: 'dataview',
                                        id: 'myDataView',
                                        autoHeight:true,
                                        reference: 'dataview',
                                        itemSelector: 'div.dataview-multisort-item',
                                        store: Ext.create('Admin.store.users.UsersAvatarStore'),
                                        tpl: [
                                            '<tpl for=".">',
                                                '<div>',
                                                   '<a href="#">',
                                                       '<img id="{name}" src="resources/images/default-avatars/{thumb}" height="72" weigh="72"/>',
                                                   '</a>',
                                                '</div>',
                                            '</tpl>',
                                             ]                                     
                                    }
```

Comment: Hello Eseresaure, Do you want images to appear inline (horizontal) with respect to panel width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the css inside tpl like this:

```
'<tpl if="this.check(values)">',
      '<div  class="menu-item" style="display: block!important; width: 100% !important;" event="myevent"><span class="fa-toggle-off"></span><span class="menu-text" style=" width: 162px;">' + text + '</span></div>',
     '<tpl else >'
```

> This is just a small example hope you can relate to this and it solves
>   your problem.